# Array of string toUpperCase() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following string array

```
let example = ["hello", "what"];
```

I want to convert this array's to this:

```
 ["Hello", "what"];
```

To accomplish that I have following code:

```
example[0][0] = example[0][0].toUpperCase();
```

When I try to console.log(example), I get

```
["hello", "what"]
```

What's wrong here? How can I convert first element's first letter to upper case?

Comment: Strings cannot be changed. You have to make a completely new string and replace `example[0]`.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's the correct answer, but why we cannot directly modify a string?

Comment: Do you only want "Hello" to be capitalized, and not also "what", as the question states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
example = ["hello", "eat"];
var camelCaseArray = [];
for(var x = 0; x < example.length; x++){
    camelCaseArray.push(example[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+example[x].slice(1));
}
console.log(camelCaseArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope that can help.

```
let example = ["hello", "what"];

example = example.map(ar => ar[0].toUpperCase() + ar.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let example = ["hello", "what"];

example[0] = example[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +  example[0].substring(1);

console.log(example);
```

Comment: Does not provides the required result. The second string should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

try this one too.

```js
let example = ["hello", "what"];

example[0] = example[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + example[0].slice(1);
console.log(example);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have two square brackets? You only need one...

```
example[0]=example[0].toUpperCase();
```

Comment: That produces: ["HELLO","what"]